# not able to build executable jar using maven shade plugin

Tags: jar, executable, maven-shade-plugin

i need to check the anagram java file using the maven shade plugin and need to add the manifest and build number . i have tried below code.

```
<project XML="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.fresco.play</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-anagram-finder</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>maven-anagram-finder</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <!-- Insert test dependency here -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <mainClass>com.fresco.play.Anagram</mainClass>
                                <Build-Number>10</Build-Number>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

this is the error i am getting while trying to build using the jdk1.8 version. all the test cases are passing but build is failing with this error

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 48.286 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-25T09:23:24+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.1:shade (default) on project maven-anagram-finder: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.1:shade for parameter transformer: Cannot create instance of interface org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ResourceTransformer: org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ResourceTransformer.<init>() -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginConfigurationException
```

i have tried all the ways. but not able to resolve. could you please help on this??

Comment: i have fixed the issue by adding the transformer implementation. Thank you.

Comment: this is the final code.

Comment: If you fixed the issue yourself I suggest that you either post the fix as an Answer or close the question.

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved the issue by adding the transformer implementation. Thank you.

4.0.0
com.fresco.play
maven-anagram-finder
jar
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
maven-anagram-finder
http://maven.apache.org

```
<!-- Insert test dependency here -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>maven-anagram-finder</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.fresco.play.Anagram</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>com.fresco.play.Anagram</Main-Class>
                                    <Build-Number>10</Build-Number>
                                </manifestEntries>

                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```